# How To Download Magento 2.2.2 with Sample data using Composer?

Tags: magento2, composer, magento2.2.2

I know how to install Magento 2 using composer. Magento latest release of version Magento 2.2.2. I don't know how to download or Installation with sample data Using Composer. I try to run direct

```
"composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.2.2 ."
```

But I need direct inject with sample data. It's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can either install sample data before or after installation of magento.

#### Before installation

Here is a list of all sample data modules which you can add to you composer.json

```
"magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-cms-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-widget-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-review-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-customer-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-wishlist-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-sales-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-tax-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-msrp-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-product-links-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-swatches-sample-data": "100.1.*",
"magento/sample-data-media": "100.1.*",
"magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.1.*",
```

#### After installation

Simply follow this instruction: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html

In short run: `php bin/magento sampledata:deploy && composer install && php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question - is that possible to inject command with composer command? @ Bartosz

Comment: Like "composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.2.2 ." - is dictly download magento2 command but i need with sample data. understand?

Comment: I totally understand. It is obvious that you cant do it with composer create-project but you can require sample modules after, what is the deal?

Comment: You mean after composer command I need to run "php bin/magento sampledata:deploy" that's one?

Comment: No. Either, create project with composer then require all sample modules i listed or create project, install magento and then run after installation command.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, you can't install sample data in composer command itself.

You can check the documentation and all the parameters that can used for the same [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html)

If you want to install the sample data you can always follow @Bartosz Herba 's answer.